# Mapbox - everything disappears at zoom level 15, fine at 14.99

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I can't figure out why mapbox stops displaying my map layer at zoom level 15. I have the source set to maxzoom of 16. I'm using TileServer PHP to serve an OpenMapTiles.com file. I was hoping to overzoom down to a street view. Here's a gif of what I'm enountering, as well as my style.json (adapted from osm-bright)

## HTML

```
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'asdfasdfasdf';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'styles/osm-bright/style.json'
    });
    </script>
```

## style.json

(too big for SO)
`https://pastebin.com/Ahdkrcky`

## GIF

`https://i.imgur.com/OOb3HlT.gifv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-php/issues/138#issuecomment-431416643

This was my issue, a friend recommended I check the Network tab of electron, and I saw HTTP 203 errors. My tileset only supported zoom levels of 14 max, so by setting this under the sources:

```
"sources": {
    "openmaptiles": {
      "type": "vector",
      "tiles": ["http://pi4/2017-07-03_us_pennsylvania/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"],
      "minzoom": 0,
      "maxzoom": 14
    }
```

That says the maxzoom of 14 is all my pbf's can serve, overzoom clientside on the rest :-)

Let me know if this helps you too!